# Rails3: how to style the different elements of a collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, listbox, styling

I dynamically build a pick-list with a collection I retrieve from a table, using "collection_select".
I would like to color differently the list items, according to an attribute from the collection, ie :

black if they're available /
grey if they're not.

How can I do this ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by myself. I use the parameter 
    :disabled => << sub-collection >>